# Dramatic differences between UFRaw, GIMP, and JPG displays

Tags: photo-editing, gimp

I recently downloaded [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and I am having a slight issue. When I import a RAW image into GIMP, tinker with it (using the [UFRaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFRaw) plug-in), and then press OK, the displayed image (in the GIMP preview) is very different from the image I edited. Moreover, when I then export the image from GIMP to a *.jpg, the image is yet again different.

The difference lies in the colours; in the GIMP preview, yellows & greens are very much accentuated and the image appears slightly darker. Upon export the issue is slightly less pronounced but the picture is still not the same as the picture I finished editing in UFRaw

- Any ideas as to why this is happening?
- Is there a way to fix this so that all three displays agree (UFRaw, GIMP, and Preview [computer is a Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard, if that helps])

**Example:**

[image: Photo as it appears post-editing in UFRaw]

*Photo as it appears post-editing in UFRaw*

[image]

*Photo as it appears in GIMP after pressing OK in UFRaw*

[image]

*Photo as it appears in JPG format after export*

Any help would be most welcome, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an environment without color calibration. Furthermore, the JPEG does not seem to have embedded color information.

I sometimes have the same. Edit a picture in Photoshop - nice. (Photo has embedded color profile, Photoshop can handle that). Then save in JPEG with conversion to sRGB, then preview it - super ugly. (The previewer does not handle the embedded color profile). Open with Fireworks - colors are fine. Upload to sites - colors are nice again.

So basically you will have to make sure you are in a color-managed environment, the image contains embedded color profile and your preview tools can handle the embedded color profile.

Alternatively, use a color-managed environment, generate outputs without embedded color profile to sRGB. Then the pictures will look okay.